# Word problem by modelling a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

> A crew of workers did one job for a certain number of days. If they
>   were three more, they would have finished $2$ days earlier; if they were $12$ more, the same work would have done $5$ days earlier. I should determine the number of workers in the crew and the days for which the work was completed.

I think it is best if $x$ is the number of workers and $y$ are the days for which the work is done. Now I am trying to find a relationship between the number of workers and the days that are required. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assume that the amount of work done (in worker-days) is the product of the number of workers and the number of days, so the work done by $x$ workers in $y$ days is $xy$.

If we increase the number of workers by $3$ and decrease the number of days by $2$ then the work done is $(x+3)(y-2)$. But this should be the same as the work done by $x$ workers for $y$ days. So we have

$xy = (x+3)(y-2)$

In the same way, we also have

$xy = (x+12)(y-5)$

By re-arranging these two simultaneous equations you can find the values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you explain the first sentence you wrote? I am not sure I understand it. The work $A=P.t$, where $P$ is the efficiency (performance per unit time) and $t$ is the time. Why do we assume that the amount of work done is the product of the number of workers and the number of days?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova I am assuming the workers are all identical and the efficiency of each worker is $1$ worker-day per day. If the workers work at different rates then there is not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: I am trying to understand, but I am not sure I do. You accept that the efficiency of each worker is $1$ worker-day per day. What does this mean? The workers are all identical?

Comment: We have $x$ workers, $1$ job and $y$ days and we are trying to find the amount of work done as we assume the workers are all identical. How to take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: define $f$ to be the fraction of the job that one crew member is able to accomplish in one day.

Translate every sentence into an equation involving $f$ (as well as your $x$ and $y$), and solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: We don't know that every worker works at the same pace as the others.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova This is true, but if you don't assume it, then there is no solution. In absence of any information, always assume that everything is homogeneous.